# RIA Services method signature to pass Bitmap as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, wcf-ria-services

I try to save a screenshot into the DB. But I cannot figure out the RIA Services method signature to do it. Any clue, please!

```
///////// Client Code /////////////////
    Graphics gfx;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
//////////////////////////////////////


[Invoke]
public void SaveScreen(?????)
{

}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server code has to look like this:

```
[Invoke]
public void SaveScreen(byte[] image)
{
    // Code to store the image in the database
}
```

For using this you just have to write the bitmap into an array of bytes (for example by saving it to a `MemoryStream` and invoking the stream's `ToArray()` method) and push it to the server.

Comment: In some cases will this solution works, but if the image is to big (to many bytes) an wcf exception gets raised.

Comment: @Jehof It's correct what you said. I got some error. But I increased some values  maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000". And it works fine.

Comment: You are aware of it, but may be Dmitry Boyko isn´t. I expect that his next question is, why he gets an exception when he tries to send his bitmap to the server.